# Inverse Transpose of Jacobian Matrix

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, matrices, jacobians

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bijective function. Fixed $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$. For any $x$ closes to $a$, using Taylor's series we can approximate $f(x)$ by 
\begin{equation}
f(x)\approx f(a)+Jf_a(x-a)
\end{equation}
where $Jf_a$ is the Jacobian Matrix at $a$.

I'd like to know the relation between $((Jf_a)^{-1})^T(x-a)$ and the function $f$. What I know is $(Jf_a)^{-1}=Jf^{-1}_{f(a)}$. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance

Comment: @Jiamprong Is it  a  good idea to consider the following related question: Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the vector space  of all smooth maps from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to itself. Is there a linear map $Z:\mathcal{S} \to \mathcal{S}$ with the following property: for each $f\in \mathcal{S}$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ we have $(Jf_{a})^{T}=J Z(f)_{f(a)}$?

Comment: @AliTaghavi: Are they equivalent?

Comment: @Jiamprong They are not equivalent but I think that my question is  somehow related to your question.